# Assembly: LC3 Division

Tags: assembly, division, lc3

I'm very new to the assembly language and in class we're working on a division program using the LC3 simulator.
Below is my code for my division algorithm.

```
DIVISION:

AND     R3, R3, 0   ; Zero out R3 /This is the remainder
AND R4, R4, 0   ; Zero out R4 /This is the quotient

NOT     R3, R2      ; Takes the inverse of 2nd input ->R3
ADD     R3, R3 #1   ; Add one to the inverse (for 2s comp)

LOOPD
ADD     R4, R4, #1  ; Add 1 to R4 repeatedly
ADD     R1, R1, R3  ; Subtract input2 from R1
BRN     NEGATIVE
BRZ     ZERO
BRP     LOOPD

NEGATIVE
ADD     R4, R4, #-1
ADD     R3, R1, R2

; Done with divison algorithm.
ZERO
LD  R0, DECCONV     ; Load Decimal converter
ADD     R3, R3, R0  ; Convert back to ASCII
ADD     R4, R4, R0  ; Convert back to ASCII

ST  R3, REMRESULT   ; Store the remainder result
ST  R4, DIVRESULT   ; Store the division result.

LD  R0, DIVRESULT   ; Load Division result into R0
PUTC            ; Print it.
LEA     R0, DIVSTRING   ; Load the string for division.
PUTS            ; Print the string.

LD  R0, REMRESULT   ; Load Remainder result into R0
PUTC            ; Print it.
LEA     R0, REMSTRING   ; Load the string for remainder
PUTS            ; Print the string.
```

When I enter two inputs, for example: 4 and 2.
I get 2 for the quotient and 1 for the remainder.
When I enter 9,3 I get 6 remainder 1..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the simulator to single step the code and find where it goes wrong.
That said, it's obvious that the `ZERO` case still has the remainder in `R1` so using `R3` is wrong. I recommend you keep the remainder in `R1` for the `NEGATIVE` block too and adjust the final part of the code for this.

The quotient should have been fine, I don't know why you got `6` for the `9/3` (if you really did).